# React state loop on conditional if

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Have some confusion in using the react state, as from my code below, when trying to hit the API, the `res2` will be running twice, and `res3` will be running 4 times, and so on going deeper on the nested if.

Is there any way to only hit each one of the API chains once, then after hitting each API would update the `taskNum` state and render it on screen?

```js
function Loading() {
  const [taskNum, setTaskNum] = useState(1);
  const location = useLocation();

  const client = axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://localhost:8000"
  });

  const predictImage = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const res1 = await client.post(`/get-box/${location.state.id}`);

      if (res1 && !(res1["data"]["img_id"] === -1)) {
        setTaskNum(2);
        const res2 = await client.post(
          `/get-img/${res1["data"]["img_id"]}`
        );
        console.log("response 2");

        if (res2) {
          setTaskNum(3);
          const res3 = await client.post(
            `/super/${res2["data"]["historyId"]}`
          );
          console.log("response 3");

          if (res3) {
            setTaskNum(4);
            const res4 = await client.post(
              `/easy/${res3["data"]["historyId"]}`
            );
            console.log("response 4");

            if (res4) {
              setTaskNum(5);
              const res5 = await client.post(
                `/get-history/${res4["data"]["historyId"]}`
              );
              console.log("response 5");

              if (res5) navigate("/hasil", { state: res5["data"] });
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      setTaskNum(0);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    predictImage();
  }, []);
```

### get description function

```js
const getDescription = (num) => {
  if (num === -1) {
    return "Oh no...";
  }
  if (num === 1) {
    return "Done Uplo...";
  }
  if (num === 2) {
    return "Found the..";
  }
  if (num === 3) {
    return "Plates are ready....";
  }
  if (num === 4) {
    return "Eureka..";
  }
  if (num === 5) {
    return "All Done..";
  }
  return "I'm sorry but..";
};
```

### my render return

```js
  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto mt-16 mb-24">
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center mt-16">
        <ScaleLoader
          color="#3F83F8"
          height={30}
          speedMultiplier={0.8}
          width={8}
        />
        <div className="mt-6 text-xl font-medium">Doing Some Magic!</div>
        <span className="mt-1 text-center font-medium text-gray-500">
          {taskNum}/5 Task
          <br /> {getDescription(taskNum)}
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've been trying to nest the `setTaskNum` on conditional `if` and `function` to handle updates, but all of them always hit the API multiple times.

```js
if (res1 && !(res1["data"]["userId"] === -1)) {
  if (taskNum === 1) {
    console.log("setTaskNum(2)");
    setTaskNum(2);
  }
  const res2 = await client.get(`/users/${res1["data"]["userId"]}`);
  console.log("response 2");
```

---

> **EDIT** My real API has a long processing time, it is Machine Learning related (inference image)

Live preview of the error see in console

[image: Edit React state loop on conditional if]

Comment: `res1`, `res2`, etc are response values, can you clarify what you mean by "running"? What are the steps to reproduce?

Comment: sorry if that wasn't clear enough, what I mean by running is the axios.post method that hit the API, the client.post() will do post 2 times, 1 for the first time _and the second i think after the state is updated_. The API will instantly get running after the page load.

Comment: Think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: got it live in [here](https://codesandbox.io/live/5a167a80f63)

Comment: The sandbox link doesn't appear to be live any more.

Comment: Kindly move to freeze version [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-state-loop-on-conditional-if-ko8ngs?file=/src/Loading.js)

Comment: What I see is the `useEffect` being run twice basically. I see only ***two*** of each log. Can you confirm this is what you actually see as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was able to resolve it by myself,

1. Defining global variable

```js
const defaultPredictRes = {
  res1: null,
  res2: null,
  res3: null,
  res4: null,
  taskNum: null
};
```

2. Passing it to the `useState()`

```js
const [predictRes, setPredictRes] = useState(defaultPredictRes);
```

3. Set the useState() within conditional

```js
      if (predictStep === 0) {
        const apiRes1 = await client.get(`...`);
        console.log("res1", apiRes1);
        if (apiRes1.data)
          setPredictRes((curRes) => ({
            ...curRes,
            res1: apiRes1.data,
            taskNum: 1
          }));
      }

      if (predictStep === 1 && predictRes.res1?.userId) {
        const apiRes2 = await client.get(`...`);
        console.log("res2", apiRes2);
        if (apiRes2)
          setPredictRes((curRes) => ({
            ...curRes,
            res2: apiRes2.data,
            taskNum: 2
          }));
      }
```

4. Create 2 useEffect(), to compensate multiple API catch at first page load.

```js
  // first render + first initiate, componentDidMount()
  useEffect(() => {
    setPredictRes((curRes) => ({ ...curRes, taskNum: 0 }));
  }, []);

  // next stepper
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("step", predictRes);
    predictImage(predictRes.taskNum);
  }, [predictRes.taskNum]);
```

---

**Console Result**

[image]

---

**Full Code**

[image: Edit React state loop on conditional if]

Answer (score 1):

What I see is the `useEffect` being run twice basically. I see ***only two*** of each log.

[image]

This seems to be caused by rendering the app into a `React.StrictMode` component which double-invokes certain lifecycle methods and functions as a way to help you detect [unexpected side-effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects). Function component bodies are one of these. What I see missing from the code is any `useEffect` hook cleanup function to cancel/abort any in-flight network requests.

You should return a cleanup function to do this.

Example:

```
// Moved outside component to remove it as a dependency
const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com"
});

function Loading() {
  const [taskNum, setTaskNum] = useState(1);

  const predictImage = useCallback(async ({ controller }) => { // <-- receive controller
    try {
      console.log("before res 1");

      const res1 = await client.get(`/posts/1`, { signal: controller.signal }); // <-- pass controller signal
      console.log(res1);
      console.log("response 1");

      if (res1) {
        setTaskNum(2);
        console.log("setTaskNum(2)");
        const res2 = await client.get(`/users/${res1["data"]["userId"]}`, {
          signal: controller.signal // <-- pass controller signal
        });
        console.log("response 2");
        console.log(res2);
        if (res2) {
          setTaskNum(3);
          console.log("setTaskNum(3)");
          const res3 = await client.get(`/comments/${res2["data"]["id"]}`, {
            signal: controller.signal // <-- pass controller signal
          });
          console.log("response 3");
          console.log(res3);
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      setTaskNum(0);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController(); // <-- create controller

    predictImage({ controller }); // <-- pass controller

    return () => controller.abort(); // <-- return cleanup function to abort
  }, [predictImage]);

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-state-loop-on-conditional-if]

[image]

Comment: yes, it's right, each API has been hit twice. I do use the ```React.StrictMode``` on the app file, should I remove it too?

Comment: had it tried on my real API it still produces multiple outputs on the same API, also based on my search the ```controller.abort``` will cancel API that takes some time to load, considering my real API has some heavy load data/ processing (ML related), is there any other possibilities to do such API chain while not running each API twice?

Comment: @NicholasNanda No, I would recommend/suggest removing the `StrictMode` component since it's there to help you detect unexpected side-effects and other issues in your app.

Comment: @NicholasNanda Not really, nothing off the top of my head. If you need to fetch data then you just need to do it and wait for it to complete. I don't see any way for multiple outputs on the same API to occur unless the `predictImage` is called more than once. Are you *sure* your real code is only calling the function once at-a-time?

Answer (score 0):

> The second parameter to setState() is an optional callback function that will be executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

So, using class components (`constructor`, `render` etc),

```
async predictImage() {
    var res1 = await ...;
    if(res1) {
        this.setState({taskNum: 2}, ()=> {
            var res2 = await ...;
            if(res2) {
                this.setState({taksNum: 3}, ()=> {
                    var res3 = await ...;
                    if(res3) {
                        this.setState({taskNum: 4}, ()=>{
                            var res4 = await ...;
                            if(res4) {
                            }
                        );
                     }     
}
```

Since you're calling `predictImage` from inside `useEffect(..,[])`,
you can call it from inside `componentDidMount` or even rename `predictImage` to `componentDidMount`.

If you are using React Router <= 5, `useLocation` can be replaced with `withRouter`.
For React Router 6+, see (https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/faq)

Comment: can you elaborate more about using ```this.setState()``` by using the classes, tried and found out _TypeError: this.setState is not a function_

Comment: I meant React Class Components.

Comment: Chaining `this.setState` callbacks to enqueue further state updates is a React anti-pattern. Use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle to handle this. This is similar in function to what the `useEffect` hook does in React function components.